# Create multiple text files from single text file with text found between a repeating identical pattern

Tags: sed, grep

I have a text file of the form:

> pattern
>
> info
>
> pattern
>
> different info
>
> pattern
>
> more different info

This repeats 50 times. I'd like to take this file and create 50 files each of which just contains:

> pattern
>
> whatever info is below and stoping just before the next header.

To be clear, the pattern is exactly the same all 50 times and then it has unique data below it.

Could someone please tell me how to do this with grep or sed or something?

Thanks

Comment: define new files naming convention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '/pattern/{close(f); f="file" ++c ".out"} f{print>f}' file
```

This creates files file1.out, file2.out, etc with info starting with `pattern`.

#### How it works

- `/pattern/{close(f); f="file" ++c ".out"}`

  Every time that we see a line matching regex `pattern`, close file `f` and assign a new name to `f`.  `c` is a counter which is incremented every time that we see `pattern`.
- `f{print>f}`

  If `f` is nonempty (meaning that we have seen the first occurrence of `pattern`), then print the current line to file `f`.

#### Example

Let's start with this sample file:

```
$ cat file
pattern
info
pattern
different info
pattern
more different info
```

Now, let's run our command and look at the output files that it creates:

```
$ awk '/pattern/{close(f); f="file" ++c ".out"} f{print>f}' file
$ cat file1.out
pattern
info
$ cat file2.out
pattern
different info
$ cat file3.out
pattern
more different info
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split

```
split -l 4 infile
```